# skiping systemd generators possible? recipe for replacing generators by native unit files?

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi

I'd like to speed up the boot process on a rpi zero w.
The systemd generator phase took around 1.7s on that system.

By disabling some generators where I think they are not used in this setup the time could already be reduced to 0.9s (see below)

According to my understanding, the generators are regenerating unit files each boot (or at least checking if new unit files needs to be generated). So basically they want to offer some flexibility in case of changes.
I'd like to fix things, there is no dynamic adaptation needed, and if changes are needed, I am aware and could trigger a manual regeneration.

**My question is, if there is a foreseen way to skip the generator phase somehow?

If not, is there an recipe for replacing generators with native unit files?**

The following generators are still in place on that system, do I really need them?

- systemd-fstab-generator
- systemd-getty-generator
- systemd-gpt-auto-generator
- systemd-sysv-generator

The following generators I don't need, at least that's what I think I understood from their man pages
(please let me know if I did something stupid here)

```
sudo chmod a-x /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-rc-local-generator 
sudo chmod a-x /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-cryptsetup-generator 
sudo chmod a-x /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-debug-generator 
sudo chmod a-x /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-bless-boot-generator 
sudo chmod a-x /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-hibernate-resume-generator
sudo chmod a-x /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-run-generator 
sudo chmod a-x /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-system-update-generator 
sudo chmod a-x /lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-veritysetup-generator
```

br
Arne

Comment: did u got any solutions to this, as i was also looking into optimizing the systemd init for embedded linux.

Comment: no, unfortunately not.
I managed to disable some generators which are fore sure of no use in my system.
As far as I understood the generators is an approach to use system v config files and translate them into native unit files. So it might work for many generators to copy the generated unit files to static locations and disable the corresponding generators.
I am really wondering that no one did this before, systemd isn't that new.